# MinGW (C) makefile with subdirectories

Tags: c, windows, powershell, makefile, mingw

I've got a kind of a technical question for you, here's the context:
We are working on a group project in C using raylib (which is great btw) we are expected to use only make for compilation (therefore no CMake) I'm working on linux so it goes really well and smooth, here is the makefile:

```
SHELL := bash
.ONESHELL:
.SHELLFLAGS := -eu -o pipefail -c
.DELETE_ON_ERROR:
MAKEFLAGS += --warn-undefined-variables
MAKEFLAGS += --no-builtin-rules

# C Compilation Configuration
TARGET_EXEC ?= app.out

CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -lm -lraylib -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lX11 -L lib/

BUILD_DIR ?= ./build
SRC_DIRS ?= ./src

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name "*.c")
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)        

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
    $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)
    
MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p
```

It is pretty simple for what it does is just finding all the .c files in the src folder, compiling them and putting them into the same subdirectories in the build folder
Here's what it looks like:

[image: Folder tree after using make]

Now here's the problem:
My friend are working on windows with minGw (and one of them is stuck with it, he can't get cygwin or wsl installed) So we need to deal with it

So here's what i made for them:

```
TARGET_EXEC ?= app.exe
    
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g -lm -lraylib -lGL -lm -L lib/

BUILD_DIR ?= ./build
SRC_DIRS ?= ./src

SRCS := $(shell powershell "(Get-ChildItem $(subst /,,$(SRC_DIRS)) -Recurse -Include *.c | Resolve-Path -Relative"))

OBJS := $(subst src,build,$(SRCS))
OBJS := $(OBJS:.c=.o)


$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(CFLAGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
    powershell "if (!(Test-Path '$(dir $@)')) { mkdir '$(dir $@)' }"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@


.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @echo $(OBJS)
    rmdir /s build
```

But i can't make it work on my own windows.
I'll take care of merging the twos but for now only the windows one isn't working
I've heard about sub-directories makefile but it feels like it's even harder to manage and i'm not looking neither for hardcoded makefile
Futhermore, minGw doesn't include any unix based command (like find)

EDIT: this is a school project so i don't see any problems in letting you clone it if you wanna take a closer look

Any help is appreciated,
thanks

Comment: If your friend is using the MinGW compiler suite then I would suggest that they go with [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) as well.  With the combination of those, one can (generally speaking) build native applications on Windows using the same makefile that works on Linux.

Comment: Note also that it looks like the issue would not arise in the first place if you enumerated the source files explicitly (and there are only four, so that shouldn't be a big deal) and used appropriate `make` rules for creating subdirectories, instead of doing that in the recipes of the object files.  Or even (gasp!) build the objects in the same folders as their corresponding sources, which is the traditional approach.

Comment: I'm fairly confident that these invocations of `powershell` are not doing what you want them to do.  Have you looked at the content of the `SRCS` variable for example to see what it contains?  You can use `$(info SRCS = $(SRCS))` after it's set to see what it's set to.  I suspect it's not what you want.  Also I don't know why you're removing all the slashes in the `SRC_DIRS` value with `$(subst /,,$(SRC_DIRS))` ??

Comment: Really, you should use MSYS2 shell and use the same Makefile for all platforms. You may need to set a variable to `.exe` to specify the extension if it is Windows. Also note that CMake can generate Makefiles, so you can use CMake and still use make. See the following link for an example Makefile that works on Windows+MSYS2 and on macOS and Linux: https://github.com/brechtsanders/ci-test/blob/master/Makefile